# 2 anchor with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here is my code

```
<a href="#" class="slider-1-prev">prev</a>
<a href="#" class="slider-2-prev">prev</a>
```

How do I make it both click if I click any of it ?

If I click .slider-1-prev, at the same I click .slider-2-prev
If I click .slider-2-prev, at the same I click .slider-2-prev

How to make it by javascript ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For the audience at home: Please *do* clarify *why* you need to click the other prev button? :)

Comment: I have 2 slider and both need slide together when I click next and previous button. Mean when I click next button, both slide need to move to next slide together. Do you know what I mean ?

Comment: That's what I thought. Answer posted below (with a shorter version you may prefer). :)

Comment: $(".slider-1-prev").click(function () {
    $(".slider-2-prev").trigger('click');
});
$(".slider-2-prev").click(function () {
    $(".slider-1-prev").trigger('click');
});

Comment: @Tushar Raj: Infinite recursion and crash. Sorry.

Comment: Need to unbind the click event :P

Comment: @Tushar Raj: Also mentioned in answer below. Please read answers too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as triggering the event on the *other* link, you need to shield against infinite repeating (e.g. with a shield variable):

```
var inClick = false;
$(document).ready(function {
    $('.slider-1-prev').on('click', function {
        if (!inClick) {
            inClick = true;
            $('.slider-2-prev').trigger('click');
            inClick = false;
        }
    });
    $('.slider-2-prev').on('click', function {
        if (!inClick) {
            inClick = true;
            $('.slider-1-prev').trigger('click');
            inClick = false;
        }
    });
})
```

If you want a shorter version, you can listen for both on one handler and click "the other":

```
var inClick = false;
$(document).ready(function {
    var $sliders = $('.slider-1-prev,.slider-2-prev');
    $sliders.on('click', function {
        if (!inClick) {
            inClick = true;
            // Click the one that was not clicked (not this)
            $sliders.not(this).trigger('click');
            inClick = false;
        }
    });
})
```

Another option is a bit more complicated as you need to turn the handler `off` and then `on` again. Stick with this simple one for now.

The on/off approach involves disabling the handling while executing it, so that it will not trigger again until you reconnect it. The downside is you need to reference a separate function so that it can effectively reference itself:

```
$(document).ready(function {
    var $sliders = $('.slider-1-prev,.slider-2-prev');

    // Define separate named function 
    var clickTheOtherOne = function(){
        // Disable the click
        $sliders.off('click');

        // Click the one that was not clicked (not this)
        $sliders.not(this).trigger('click');

        // Reenable the click handler
        $sliders.on('click', clickTheOtherOne);
    }
    // Initial enabling of the handler
    $sliders.on('click', clickTheOtherOne);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're going to behave the same, why not define only one function for both?

```
$('.slider-1-prev, .slider-2-prev').click(function(){
    //... mutual code
});
```

Comment: They are probably trying to keep two separate displays in sync. This will not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure why you need to do what you ask, but try this approach:

js code:

```
// this will work on all classes that start with 'slider-prev'
$('*[class^="slider-prev"]').on('click',function{
          // do something
});
```

Of course you will need to alter your htm code to:

```
<a href="#" class="slider-prev-1">prev</a>
<a href="#" class="slider-prev-2">prev</a>
```

Comment: They are probably trying to keep two displays in sync. This will not do that.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie its possible, yeah. But can't be sure on what OP wants exactly

Comment: It was the only thing that made sense given the details. I guess we will see (once they explain) :)

Answer (score -1):

this should do the trick

```
$(document).ready(function{
     $('.slider-1-prev').on('click',function{
          $('.slider-2-prev').trigger('click');
     });
     $('.slider-2-prev').on('click',function{
          $('.slider-1-prev').trigger('click');
     });
})
```

Comment: this may lead to cyclic clicks one after other and keep going

Comment: My bad, i just realize this. Thanks Bhushan :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
$('.slider-1-prev').click(function(){
 $('.slider-2-prev').trigger('click');
});

// If you need the opposite, then do - 
$('.slider-2-prev').click(function(){
 $('.slider-1-prev').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I would probably not test this.. and just delete it instead